# Who are the other two girls whose hair Araragi has cut?

Tags: monogatari-series

In the last episode of Hanamonogatari, near the end of the episode where Araragi prepares to cut Kanbaru's hair, he said "You are the third girl whose hair I'm cutting".

Who was the other two girls that got their hair cut by Araragi?

Answer (score 7):

One of the two girls is Hanekawa Tsubasa. Remember that during the events in *Karen Bee*<sup>1</sup>, she underwent an image change where her usual braided hair was replaced by bob cut, and her glasses replaced by contact lens. Her hair was actually cut by Araragi when she went out with him to karaoke in the short story *Tsubasa Song*<sup>2</sup>, which takes place some time after *Tsubasa Cat* and before *Karen Bee*.

I don't know who the other girl is. There are many characters whose hairstyle has changed between the First Season and the Second Season of the light novel series, but they are not cut by Araragi:

- Senjougahara Hitagi: She cut her hair short between the events of *Karen Bee* and *Tsukihi Phoenix* to break away from her past and start anew<sup>3</sup>.
- Kanbaru Suruga: She initially kept her hair short in *Suruga Monkey*. However, after she was saved by Araragi, she started **growing** her hair<sup>3</sup> up until the end of Hanamonogatari.
- Hanekawa Tsubasa: After *Tsubasa Tiger*, her hair became black and white stripes like that of the white tiger she absorbed<sup>4</sup>. This is only a change in color, though.
- Araragi Karen: In *Tsukihi Phoenix*, she nonchalantly **cut off her own** ponytail so that she could piggyback Araragi as a punishment game<sup>4</sup>. Araragi does not cut her hair himself. In the anime, she seems to grow her ponytail back a little in *Hanamonogatari* (episode 5).
- Araragi Tsukihi: In the anime, story-wise chronologically, she had mid-back level hair in *Nekomonogatari (Black)* (episode 1), then bob cut hair in *Nisemonogatari*, then very long braided hair in *Nekomonogatari (White)*, then straight waist-length hair in *Hanamonogatari* (episode 5). However, she is said to change her hairstyle very often<sup>3</sup>, so it is very unlikely that Araragi has anything to do with it.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Light novel - Nisemonogatari Volume 1 - Karen Bee Chapter 011. Anime - Nisemonogatari Episode 4</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Published in Bakemonogatari Anime Complete Guidebook. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Monogatari_novels#List_of_short_short_stories).</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> Light novel - Nisemonogatari Volume 2 - Tsukihi Phoenix Chapter 005.</sup>
<sup><sup>4</sup> Light novel - Nekomongatari (White) - Tsubasa Tiger Chapter 066. Anime - Monogatari Series: Second Season Episode 5.</sup>
<sup><sup>5</sup> Light novel - Nisemonogatari Volume 2 - Tsukihi Phoenix Chapter 005. Anime - Nisemonogatari Episode 9.</sup>

Comment: Nadeko Sengoku also went through a minor hairstyle change during Otorimonogatari when Tsukihi-chan cut off her bangs, causing her to lose her marbles. It's back to normal by the time Kaiki sees her in Koimongatari, though.

Comment: @Torisuda: that makes sense though - because there's a time skip of at least a month (iirc) between the point where Tsukihi chats with her and when Senjougahara asks Kaiki for help.

Comment: @Maroon Yeah, I think Tsukihi-chan cuts Nadeko's hair in late October (Otori takes place around Halloween), and Kaiki sees her sometime in February. I guess it says something about Nadeko that even though by this point she's a god who even beat up Shinobu, the most powerful kai in the show, she still wants to hide behind her bangs.

Comment: Any update since then?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the 2nd girl is Tsukihi; "Tsukihi Brushing" is set some point after Araragi graduates.

A brief summary of the story: Tsukihi steps on her long hair, wants to cut it, Araragi wants to do it, dumb shenanigans ensue, Shinobu gets fed up.

A translation can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/araragi/comments/6gx8fl/monogatari_short_stories_tsukihi_brushing/).